# Why doesn't TypeScript enforce a generic parameter in callback?

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider this TypeScript code, compiled with 2.6.1:

```
function foo<T> (bar: T, baz: (T) => void) {
    const test: T = bar;
    baz(test);
}

const string: string = "a";
foo(string, num => num.parseInt());
```

I would expect the compilation to fail, because the function `foo` is called with a `string`, but the passed callback function is using a  method that is not available in `string` -- while the function signature indicates that type of argument in callback function should be the same as the type of the first parameter.

However, the code compiles and then fails in runtime.

What am I missing?

Comment: "is using a number method" --- there is no `parseInt` in the `Number.prototype`.

Comment: Try `foo<string>(...)`

Comment: Try `foo(string, (num: string) => num.parseInt());`

Comment: @zerkms fixed,thank you

Comment: look at @zerkms comment. If you try **foo("a", x => console.log(x.toFixed()))**   the compiler will tell that the property toFixed does not exist on type _string_

Comment: @betadeveloper but neither does `parseInt` -- why doesn't it fail on it?

Comment: Actually, the compiler doesn't fail for toFixed for me.

Comment: I've got TS2551: Property 'toFixed' does not ...

Answer (score 6):

Well, because `T` in `baz: (T) => void` is not a type name, it's a parameter name.

When you fix the syntax to mean what you want it to mean, you get the expected error:

```
function foo<T> (bar: T, baz: (t: T) => void) {
    const test: T = bar;
    baz(test);
}

const s: string = "a";
foo(s, num => num.parseInt()); 
// Property 'parseInt' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Granted, it's really hard to spot errors like this one - I saw it only when I pasted your code into [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and turned on `--noImplicitAny`.  `(T)` immediately got highlighted with `Parameter 'T' implicitly has an 'any' type`. Even that error was puzzling for a moment  - wait what - `T` is not a parameter, it's a type - ...!

Comment: Relevant [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-i-get-type-checking-for-number--string-or-t--t)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue as well!